# Android: Not able to get location name from Google Geocoding API

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I'm trying to get location name from Latitude and Longitude using google reverse Geocoding API. and I'm getting error.

Here is Code I'm using :

```html
  Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
         
        try {
               
              //Place your latitude and longitude
              List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(37.423247,-122.085469, 1);
              
              TextView myAddress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if(addresses != null) {
               
                  Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                  StringBuilder strAddress = new StringBuilder();
                
                  for(int i=0; i<fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        strAddress.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                  }
                
                  myAddress.setText("I am at: " +strAddress.toString());
               
              }
               
              else
                  myAddress.setText("No location found..!");
          
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Could not get address..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Log file

```js
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.get_mobiile_location/com.example.get_mobiile_location.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
      at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
      at com.example.get_mobiile_location.MainActivity.getMyLocation(MainActivity.java:79)
      at com.example.get_mobiile_location.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
      ... 11 more
```

Please check what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Make sure your Phone GPS is on.

Comment: i m getting latitude and longtitude from google Geolocation api  
i have lat and log and i want to use these value to get the location name from google geocoder api @ShoebSiddique

Answer (score 4):

Based on the log

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

In the below line you are getting 0 addresses for the given lat,long values

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(37.423247,-122.085469, 1);
```

So to avoid the crash check the condition before accessing data from it as follows

```
if(addresses != null&&addresses.size()>0) {
  //fetch data from addresses
}else{
        //display Toast message
     }
```

**UPDATE :**

And add following permissions if you forgot anyone

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Refer following tutorial

http://karanbalkar.com/2013/11/tutorial-63-implement-reverse-geocoding-in-android/

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: i m trying what told @Nag

Comment: do i need to write special permission  ?

Comment: i used your code and now i m not getting error. u r cool, but now i m not getting location name and i changed the Coordination but still not getting, can u please give me tutorial example. or correct me  @Nag
thansk